# Why do Apple devices send wi-fi Probe Requests directed to specific SSIDs, rather than undirected Probe Requests or passively listening for Beacons?

Tags: macos, ios, wifi, privacy, ipados

This seems to be related to known networks marked "Auto-Join", though that observation could be inconclusive.

This behavior is a major privacy vulnerability since these SSIDs are broadcast wherever you go in real life.

[Private Wi-Fi Addresses](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102509) do reduce the ability to correlate device activity across different wi-fi networks. Oddly, this feature is not available on Macs, even laptops.

In addition, Apple claims that [MAC address randomization](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/wi-fi-privacy-secb9cb3140c/web) makes it so that:

> it can’t be used to persistently track a device by passive observers
> of Wi-Fi traffic

However, regardless of whether the randomized MAC address changes on some interval, and the Probe Requests directed to specific SSIDs don't all come from the same MAC address, unique combinations of SSID's, even a small number of uncommon SSIDs, over a relatively small interval can still be used to provide a good correlation that a specific device (and therefore probably a specific person) was present near a given location at a specific time. Or more targeted stalking is possible where you listen for the SSIDs broadcast by a device (person) to learn about other locations (SSIDs) where they have connected. The latter scenario may only be practical in less congested areas.

Are there specific conditions required for directed Probe Requests to be sent? Can this behavior be thwarted other than by turning off Auto-Join?

Comment: I can't check this, but probing for specific SSIDs is commonly a side-effect of having hidden SSIDs in the list of remembered connections. They then *have* to probe for them, because that's the only way to find them. That is the single major failing in thinking hidden SSIDs are 'more secure'.

Comment: Yes hidden SSIDs are problematic for privacy, but no different for security. Hidden SSIDs are supposed to handled differently, but non-hidden networks also get directed Probe Requests with the SSID included. "...devices automatically detect when a network is hidden. If a network is hidden, the iOS or iPadOS device sends a probe with the SSID included in the request—not otherwise." https://support.apple.com/guide/security/wi-fi-privacy-secb9cb3140c/web That statement is just not true.